# When is Kirino Kousaka's birthday?

Tags: oreimo

I'm just curious because Ruri's birthday was mentioned. Kirino's birthday might probably mentioned in some part of the light novel or manga.

Comment: IIRC, in Episode 10, Series I of the anime, Ayase wanted to win the Meruru figure from the cosplay contest as a birthday present for Kirino. I can't remember exactly what time of year that was, but if no one else answers, I'll do some digging later and see if I can find out.

Comment: Ah, no good; this story is Chapter 1 of Volume 4 in the novels, and it takes place in February, but it's not Kirino's birthday; it's a present for doing well in a track competition.

Comment: not sure if this is correct, but http://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZvP.png

Comment: @OshinoShinobu that's just stating the birth year.

Comment: I scoured the novels and I've been up and down the Internet, but nothing. Manami's birthday was in the novels (but who cares, right?), but not Kirino's.

Comment: @Torisuda: Would you mind writing an answer to share your failed attempt to search for Kirino's birthday? Since it seems that the information is not released, or mentioned in way not widely-known, it might be good to enumerate the media which you have confirmed to not contain Kirino's date of birth.

Comment: @nhahtdh I've done so. My confirmations of the novels and anime are somewhat tentative; at least for the novels, I can do a more in-depth, machine-aided search at some point. However, I know the contents fairly well, and I concentrated my searches on hot-spots that I thought were likely to contain the date, so if it does appear somewhere I didn't check, it was probably a random, throwaway reference.

Answer (score 5):

Her birthday is April 8. It can be seen in this [birthday plate](http://www.amiami.com/top/detail/detail?gcode=GOODS-00103195) that was revealed during [Tsukasa Fushimi's 10th anniversary](http://dengekibunko.jp/author/fushimitsukasa/) live streaming [event](http://live.nicovideo.jp/gate/lv268871612).

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching back when this question first appeared and came up with nothing. Given that Kirino is such a major character, I find it hard to believe that her canon birthday would be so hard to find, so if her birthday was ever published, it was probably in a non-canon source. It also seems probable that if her canon birthday had been published, the anime producers would have used it in the image that Oshino Shinobu linked to, instead of just the year of her birth.

I tried a few different Google searches and found this same question (unanswered) on other sites. I used Ctrl-F to search the terms "birthday", "birth", and "born" in the novels, with pretty much no result. I was relying on memory and wikia for the anime, but the anime generally doesn't include anything that wasn't in the novels. I haven't read the manga past Volume 1, or played the visual novels, so I didn't search them at all. However, I have doubts about the value of a birthday that only appears in the manga or the completely non-canon visual novels.

It is possible that I missed it in the anime or that some guidebook published as a bonus gift for people who preordered the laserdiscs in Japan contains the date.

Answer (score -1):

Okay this is really it. From my own findings, i was able to conclude that **Kirino's birthday** is **September 4, 1997**. 
From the image provided by [**Oshino Shinobu**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869/oshino-shinobu), I was able to get her birthday from her profile. It says **1997'4 生ま九**. This probably means that she was born on the **4th day** of the month of **生ま九** in the year **1997**. I tried translating it with google translate but it says "**Raw or nine**" in English.  I think I have probably made a mistake in identifying the first two characters correctly. But the important thing is the third character, **九**, which translates to "**Nine**", probably the **9th month** of the year, **September**. So I deduced that Kirino Kousaka's birthday is **September 4, 1997**.
[image]

Comment: @EdselJeddRenovalles: No, you read the thing incorrectly. It says 1997年生まれ

Comment: `1997年生まれ、千○県出身、中学二年生で陸上部○○。「休日は大好きなお兄ちゃんと買い物して過ごしてます」` Born in 1997, from Chi* (Chiba?) prefecture, (participate?) in track and field from 8th grade. "At weekend, I spend my time going shopping with my beloved older brother". (The circles are words I can't make out from the image, but the meaning shouldn't stray too far)

Comment: @nhahtdh 千葉県 is what you may look for after the first comma which is Chiba-ken (Chiba prefecture) and you are right with your guess.